# troubles with dynamic filtering in generic-display Django

Tags: django, django-1.7, django-generic-views

I am trying to display a list of the users. once you select the user you can view the userprofile. the thing is: UserProfile does not work. how to make it works?

```
#views.py
    class UserList(ListView):
        model = Userx
        template_name ='userList.html'




class UserProfile(ListView):
    template_name = 'userprofile.html'

        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            self.user= get_object_or_404(Userx, name=self.args[0])
             return Userx.objects.filter(user=self.user)
 #urls.py            

            url(r'^userprofile/(?P<id>\d+)/$', UserProfile.as_view(), name='userprofile'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the single instance you should use the [`DetailView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview) instead of the `ListView`:

```
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView

class UserProfile(DetailView):
    model = Userx
```

And change the regex group name to `pk`:

```
url(r'^userprofile/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', UserProfile.as_view(), name='userprofile')
```

Comment: I had to focus in the documentation. It's there .. Thanks dude :)